# How to add footage icons to the interface of Windows Phone 8 application ? Where to have standard icons?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8, interface, windows-phone

I am a beginner to Windows Phone. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone 8. How to add footage icons to the interface of Windows Phone 8 application ?

[image: like this]

I want to open different interfaces when user clicks that buttons. How can I achieve that ?

Where can I find the standard icons in apps ?

Comment: The "footage" is called the "application bar". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard icons pack for Windows Phone 8 you can find here:

**Dark Theme**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\Dark

**Light Theme**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\Light

---

Add an image to the project.

**In Xaml:**

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

---

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/add.png"
                                        Text="Add" 
                                        Click="AddAppBarBtn_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**In cs:**

```
private void AddAppBarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Code 
        }
```

Comment: @user3218743 I’m glad I was able to help.